# Who says Beis Shammai don't hold of "Aseh docheh lo saaseh"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, beis-shammai

A pretty ubiquitous concept in Torah is the idea of *aseh docheh lo saaseh*, that a positive *mitzvah* can override a negative precept.

I recently saw in a contemporary *sefer* that Beis Shammai don't hold of *aseh docheh lo saaseh*. It was quoting [**Sifsei Maharash** *parshas Beshalach s.v.* ובזה יש](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=39114#p=57&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=), by [**Rav Shmuel Engel**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9C) (19-20th century). I was quite surprised by this as I didn't encounter this in my delving into the topic.

I decided to look into it and managed to find that the [**Penei Yehoshua** to Beitzah 7b *s.v.* רש"י ד"ה והא](https://www.sefaria.org/Penei_Yehoshua_on_Beitzah.7a.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), brought by the [**Pardes Yosef** to Exodus 20:8 *s.v.* ובילקוט דוד](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=37692#p=214&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) says this.

> ועוד נ"ל דבלא"ה לא שייך כלל אליבא דב"ש ה"ט דאתי עשה ודחי ל"ת לשיטת רש"י שכתב בכמה דוכתי דלב"ש דפוטר סדין בציצית היינו משום דלא דריש סמוכין דגדילים תעשה לך וא"כ דאפילו בציצית גופא סובר ב"ש דלא אתי עשה ודחי ל"ת כ"ש בכל דוכתי דהא בשום דוכתא לא ידעינן ליה אלא מקרא דגדילים תעשה לך בפ"ק דיבמות.

**Rashi** ([Menachos 40a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.40a.1?lang=he&p2=Rashi_on_Menachot.40a.1.2&lang2=he); [Shabbos 25b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.25b.4?lang=he&p2=Rashi_on_Shabbat.25b.4.3&lang2=he)) says that since Beis Shammai don't make *drashos* using juxtaposed verses, they don't allow *kilayim* with *tzitzis*. The **Penei Yehoshua** sees from this that since *kilayim* with *tzitzis* is the primary source for *aseh docheh lo saaseh* (see the beginning of Yevamos), since Beis Shammai don't hold of it, they don't have a source for the concept.

I was wondering if anyone else, especially earlier, says Beis Shammai don't hold of this? Bonus points if you find someone who argues.

Comment: it looks like it's a "reasonable conclusion" - if they hold X and they don't hold Y, it follows that they don't hold the principle that is based on Y. It's a possibility, but B"S could learn "Ase dohe" from something else. It's not a logical conclusion, just speculation, IMHO. So to prove it, you need someone to state it openly, not as a conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

The Rosh in [Hilchos Tzitzis](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_on_Menachot%2C_Hilchot_Tzitzit.17.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (Found in Menachos) asks this very question on Rashi's shita:

> ועוד הקשה ר''ת ז"ל דבריש יבמות אמר אפילו מ"ד דלא דריש סמוכין בעלמא במשנה תורה דרש. ובסדר רב עמרם חשיב ו' דברים דהלכה כב"ש והך חדא מינייהו ו**בכל דוכתי קי"ל דעשה דוחה לא תעשה וילפינן לה מכלאים בציצית**.

The [Maadanei YomTov](https://www.sefaria.org/Maadaney_Yom_Tov_on_Menachot%2C_Hilchot_Tzitzit.134?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) explains the Rosh's question as follows:

> וילפינן לה מכלאים בציצית. ש"מ דרשינן סמוכים לכ"ע אף לב"ש **דדוחק לומר דבכולי דוכתי דאמרינן דאתי עשה כו' דאתיא דלא כב"ש**

Tosfos in [Shabbos 25B](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Shabbat.25b.4.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) also asks the same question on Rashi:

> ועוד דאמרינן בפ"ק דיבמות (ד' ד.) גבי כלאים בציצית דאפילו מאן דלא דריש סמוכין בעלמא במשנה תורה דריש ואיך יתכן לומר דב"ש לא דרשי סמוכין ועוד דרב עמרם גאון פוסק כב"ש בששה דברים וחשיב הך בהדייהו ועוד אמאי נקט סדין בציצית הוה ליה למנקט כלאים בציצית

And the [Maharsha](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Halachot_on_Shabbat.25b.3?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) explains the question as referring to the same question as the Rosh mentioned above:

> בא"ד ועוד דרב עמרם גאון פוסק כב"ש בששה דברים וחשיב הך בהדייהו ובכל דוכתא קי"ל דעשה דוחה ל"ת וילפינן לה מכלאים בציצית עכ"ל הרא"ש בהלכות ציצית ע"ש וכן תפרש הקושיא הכא בתוס' ודו"ק

Comment: +1 for the effort and sources. But if I understand only Maadanei YT mentions BSh (other refer to the principle of סמוכין, not עשה דוחה). Can you please elaborate on what Maadamey says in plain English?

Comment: @Alberko the Rosh mentions it in the name of Rabbeinu Tam. He asks on Rashi that it will come out that B”S won’t learn asei docheh. The Maadanei Y”T just elaborate that saying such a thing is a dochek. So in answering the question, the earliest one who says such a thing according to Rashi is R”T and he also argues. I added that Tosfos also says the same question just not as clearly but the Maharsha explains that he means this question as well